# php rand() reverse

Tags: php, функции, генераторы

Как можно на PHP написать исходник функции `srand()` и `rand()`?
Как `rand()` вычисляет значения с помощью `srand()`?
В идеале мне нужен алгоритм на PHP, который будет перемешивать массив с помощью числа сида, в конце я буду знать начальное расположение элементов массива и конечное, нужно чтобы по этим двум массивам определить, какое число сид использовалось, ну и чтобы перемешивало массив хорошо. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: `Как можно написать исходник функции rand()?`.. Может посмотреть?.. Вы ничего не путаете?... php написан на C, а не на себе самом.

Comment: скачайте [исходники](https://github.com/php/php-src) и ищите: https://github.com/php/php-src

Comment: [php_rand.h](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/php_rand.h), [rand.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/rand.c), [php_random.h](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/php_random.h), [random.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/random.c)

Comment: Я же написал, что не разбираюсь в C#, я хотел узнать, как именно вычисляет значения функция rand(), в исходник смотрел, но полностью так и не понял, поэтому и обратился сюда.

Comment: Сам алгоритм нужен конкретно на php.

Comment: определитесь что именно Вы хотите: исходники функции `rand()`  или же алгоритм...или же его реализацию на `php`. Исходник он один - и он написан на `C` ... не на `C#`!.. `С#`, `С++`, `C`, `Objective C` - это все разные языки. Если Вам нужен исходник, то он у Вас уже есть и Вам не остаётся ничего другого, как разбирать его. Если Вам нужна в этом помощь, то так и напишите. Далее...

Comment: По поводу реализаций на php... я крайне сомневаюсь что таковые имеются...ибо они уже есть в ядре языка `php`... Скажу более генерация случайных чисел, мягко говоря, непростая задача и самое эффективное до чего додумалось человечество это выдавать случайные числа на основе шума в электроцепи, добивайсь тем самым эффекта "случайности"..Собственно на этом и основан "алгоритм" исходника функции `rand` на `C`...

Comment: На Линуксе к примеру этот исходник обращается к устройству по адресу `/dev/random` или `/dev/urandom`..это как раз то самое устройство - генератор случайных чисел, которое по факту является "железкой"... или же делает системные вызовы, в зависимости от операционки, на которой вертится php... в самом php никто не "генерирует" случайных чисел...их получают от ОС или напрямую от "железок".

Comment: и что значит `реверснуть`?.. Мы говорим о необратимой операции. Опишите что Вам нужно...может Вам просто нужен "уникальный" набор символов?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random_%D0%B8_/dev/urandom

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB

Comment: В идеале мне нужен алгоритм на PHP, который будет перемешивать массив с помощью числа сида, в конце я буду знать начальное расположение элементов массива и конечное, нужно чтобы по этим двум массивам определить, какое число сид использовалось, ну и чтобы перемешивало массив хорошо. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.